# Create new ObjectProperty in Protege .The tag name is different

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, protege

I found something different when I create a new ObjectProperty. This is my [ontology](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/858d00f91092331d1d2519bf932084f3).

This ObjectProperty `hasSymptom` is been created

But now when I create new ObjectProperty `hasObject`

I founded when I create new Object Property. The `tag` name will different
1)`rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/pllab/ontologies/2013/11/untitled-ontology-2#"hasSymptom/>`

2)`rdf:about="&ont;hasObject"`

Why this happend? Thanks

Comment: What is the problem now? One is prefixed, the other not. The question would be how you created the object properties, obviously, for the second another namespace has been chosen and I don't think that this happened by chance.

Comment: @AKSW  Thank you for all your assistance. I create new ObjectProperty
using the smae way brefore. But this time create ObjectProperty `hasObject` it's show `rdf:about="&ont;hasObject"`. SO I can't find where is the problem...  SO I create a  new [ontology](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/891d8cf9994fef03f3fcc74bba6b01d7)

The new created ObjectProperty `hasObject` have same problem.
`<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&ont;hasObject"/>` 
I don't know which step when I create new ObjectProperty was missed.
Thank you for you help.

Comment: And again, what is the problem with `"&ont;hasObject"`? This is just a prefixed URI resp. a qualified name. This means the namespace of `ont` will be prepended to the token `hasObject` to get the full URI. So, what is the problem with this? It's a valid RDF/XML syntax serialization of the data.

Comment: @AKSW Thank you for all your assistance. Because in my created new [ontology](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/891d8cf9994fef03f3fcc74bba6b01d7). 
I can't using`SELECT ?x WHERE { uni:thick_tongue_fur uni:hasObject ?x . }` to get Property vaule only if I change to `<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/6/untitled-ontology-50#hasObject"/>` this type. It's mean each time I create a new ObjectProperty in my protege and I have to do this again?

Comment: See my answer. As I said, you changed something in Protege

Comment: The file must show a declaration for the ont prefix. If the declaration says ont=http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/‌​6/untitled-ontology-‌​50# then there is no difference between the two names (the XML looks different but SPARQL queries, reasoners and other tools will see no differences)

Comment: @Ignazio Thank you for you response. That is what I confused. It more helping me to learning the Sparql. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, as I already told you, you have changed something in the settings of Protege - because the default namespace for the creation of new entities doesn't change by chance.

*File* -> *Preferences* -> *New Entities* tab -> Click on *Active ontology IRI* (or change the *Specified IRI* to the one that you want)

[image]

By the way, you should use your own namespace and not that one that is auto-generated by Protege.

Comment: Thank you for all your assistance.I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem.I have been confused for a long time.it's work now. It seem i got a lot of thing to learn. Thank you :)